# Change background-image on a frequent time

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change my background image on a frequent time but it will not work somebody has an idea

```
            var pics = function() {
                var $pic_holder = $(".holder");
                var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    if ($pic_holder.css("background-image") !== "url(/picA.png)") {
                        $(".pic_holder").css("background-image", "url(/picA.png)")
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".pic_holder").css("background-image", "url(/picB.png)")
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: It could be due to your HTML, can we see the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` and don't use relative URLs. (`/picA.png`) I made a few other changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var $pic_holder = $(".holder");
      setInterval(function () {
          if ($pic_holder.css("background-image") !== "url(http://www.example.com/picA.png)") {
              $pic_holder.css("background-image", "url(http://www.example.com/picA.png)")
          }
          else{
              $pic_holder.css("background-image", "url(http://www.example.com/picB.png)")
          }
          console.log($pic_holder.css("background-image"));
      }, 1000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mj27g/

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(".pic_holder").css("background-image", "url(/picA.png)")
```

to

```
$pic_holder.css("background-image", "url(/picA.png)");
```

EDIT: Also, as everyone else has pointed out, use `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`

Comment: Still doesn't work. In the first `if` statement, `$pic_holder` returns `url(http://www.example.com/picA.png`, and not how it was set before with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try setInterval function

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to do it

```
var $pic_holder = $(".holder"),
    backChanger;

backchanger = (function backchanger () {
    if (!$pic_holder.data('bgphoto') !== 'photo-A') {
        bgUrl = '/picA.png';
        bgData = 'photo-A';
    } else {
        bgUrl = '/picB.png';
        bgData = 'photo-B';
    }

    $pic_holder.data('bgphoto', bgData).css("background-image", bgUrl);
    setTimeout(backchanger, 1000);  
}());
```

Make sure the code in if statements execute or it might be another problem.